# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't load after forced shutdown

Tags: boot, 18.04, shutdown

I was trying some shell commands in ubuntu and after i was done, i tried to shutdown the normal way, but it didnt do anything. I clicked shutdown 3 times and waited about 2 minutes but nothing happened. So i tried forced shutdown using the laptop's power button.

Now, when I try to use ubuntu, it shows me the loading screen, and then goes in a completely black screen with an underline character blinking on the top left.
If I dont do anything it keeps blinking...
If I CLICK the power button it just shuts down.

I have dual operating systems, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, the windows boots just fine, didnt see any problem there, but ubuntu is just dead.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure you didn't damage the system, and you're using HDD, sometimes you have to wait much longer than you expect. I recommend patience! wait for around 15 minutes or maybe even 30. It will work (I hope!).

If you're using SSD or you're sure you've waited long enough, simply reinstall.

There is a small chance that some system files or boot files might have been damaged (which is a very rare occurrence).

If you showed the commands you used, I could help you more. At start-up, when the system halts, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> or <kbd>f2</kbd> or... <kbd>f6</kbd> and read the information carefully. You may be able to tell what is preventing the system from booting up using that information.

Comment: As you said,  Just tried reinstalling the OS and it worked! But to answer your questions, It's on SSD, and I used a bunch of thread, sleep, and signals in C and shell for my schoolwork.

Comment: None of those commands messes with any system or boot files.If you have not executed any other command or done no other configuration (even in GUI) to the system; then, however, the roots of this problem remains a mystery.